# Store binary byte values from a FILE into C array

Tags: c, binary-data

I have a file with <strike>hexadecimals</strike> binary values and what I want is to read those values <strike>2 by 2</strike> *byte by byte* and store them into an array. I mean:

I have a file(This is not an ascii string,  I need an HEX editor to open this file)

```
00B011070000FF
```

and what I want is:

```
 ITA[0] = 00;
 ITA[1] = B0;
 ITA[2] = 11;
 ITA[3] = 07;
 ITA[4] = 00;
 ITA[5] = 00;
 ITA[6] = FF;
```

ITA is an `unsigned int`

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Solution:

```
    FILE *pFile = fopen("/ita/hex", "r");

    if (!pFile) {
            printf("Error abriendo archivo\n");
        }

    fseek(pFile, 0, SEEK_END);
    int size = ftell(pFile);
    fseek(pFile, 0, SEEK_SET);
    printf("%i\n",size);
    unsigned int ITA[size];
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        char value;
        fread(&value, 1, 1, pFile);
        ITA[i] = (unsigned int) value;
    }
    fclose(pFile);
    printf(" ITA is : %X", crcFast2(ITA, size));// crcFAST2 calculates the crc of the hexadecimals
```

Thank you again!!

Comment: Are the contents of the file in binary or in ASCII, that is, 0x00… or "00..."?

Comment: Binary, I mean 00B011070000FF is an hexadecimal value. (0x00B011070000FF)

Comment: The question is: does the file contain the characters `0`, `0`, `B`, `0`, `1`, `1` ... etc. Or is the first byte of the file 0x00, the second byte 0xB0, the third byte 0x11, and so on? And what is the type of the array you want to read into?

Comment: I try in a different way... can you read the content with a normal text editor or do you need to use an hex editor to see values?

Comment: ouh... I need an HEX editor, and ITA is an unsigned int array

Comment: Oh ok so you want to read using fread. You don't need to translate it (I was guessing you needed)

Comment: No need for "SOLVED" in the topic.

Comment: @VladLazarenko Why not?

Comment: @Ita: Because it is not the forum and nobody does it here. And after all, questions are not solved, they are answered. There was a discussion about this a year or too ago, but I don't have a link handy. I am sure you can find it on Meta somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the file contains binary data and `ITA` is an `unsigned int` array:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void readBinary(char *const filename, unsigned int *const ITA, const int size) {
    FILE *pFile = fopen(filename, "r");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        char value;
        fread(&value, 1, 1, pFile);
        ITA[i] = (unsigned int) value;
    }
    fclose(pFile);
}
```

Parameter `size` should be `7` in the scenario you described.

Comment: For clarity adding the necessary defintion of `ITA` would be nice (as it differs from the OP).

Answer (score 1):

If it is binary then you can just mmap() the file straight into memory

See [this page](http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/multipage/mmap.html) for where I have shamelessly stolen the following code

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

int fd, pagesize;
unsigned char *data; /* NB note char array not unsigned int as requested */

fd = open("foo", O_RDONLY);
pagesize = getpagesize();
data = mmap((caddr_t)0, pagesize, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, pagesize);
```

Note that the octet data will be packed into a char array, which is a preferable way to store octet data but is not what was requested

Also this: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Memory_002dmapped-I_002fO.html

Comment: You can, but that results in a char * rather than an unsigned int * as requested.

Comment: Missed that! You should almost certainly not cast the entire array / the pointer although it would probably work but should cast each value in the array when you access it; e.g. (unsigned int)ITA[i] this may or may not be a problem depending on the application. Also the char in the solution should be unsigned

Comment: No, that won't work either.  Not only would the casted unsigned int *'s overlap giving wrong data. on some platforms (arm for example) unaligned access is a bus error.  Casting is not the answer, the data must be copied from the packed form of the file to the sparse 1 byte used of every 4 form required by the asker.

Comment: `mmap()` for seven bytes seems a bit of an overkill to me.

Comment: yep fair enough I have edited the answer to make it clear it does not meet the requirements